# Is Gandaberunda mentioned in shastras?

Tags: scripture

I heard from all that its all interpolations and he is not really mentioned in shastras. Today, i come across someone who said he is mentioned in some tantras.

Comment: Yes, it's NOT mentioned in any major canonical text.